# Forcing Grails to not cache the "cache manifest" file?

Tags: html, grails, caching

I am building a Grails app that will utilize HTML5's [Offline Mode](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html). In that article, the author talks about the requirement for your web server to *not* cache something called the "**Cache Manifest**" file:

> So here’s one thing you should absolutely do: reconfigure your web server so that your cache manifest file is not cacheable by HTTP semantics.

So I need to figure out how to tell Grails (2.4.x) *not* to allow clients to cache a particular file. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6356538/4009451) but am not confident it is the generally-accepted "Grails way" of doing this.

So I ask:

- Is that answer the generally-accepted way of prohibiting a file from being cached in Grails? If not, then what is?; and
- If it is, then what is `CacheFilters`, where do I define it, and are there any docs on its `all`, `before`, `after`, `afterView`, etc. methods?

Comment: How are you serving your file, is it just laying around in web-app/ ?

Comment: Thanks @Oliver Tynes (+1) - yes, it will be in `web-app`.

Comment: I cannot tell if this is indeed the best aproach, but I had use it with success and it's quite simple. About your second concern, the Filters are predefined "rules" that run along each matching server request; they are very usefull for security checks, manipulate headers, etc. There is plenty of documentation about them in [link](http://docs.grails.org/2.2.1/guide/single.html#filters)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily control the headers in a web-app file as far as I know.

A quick workaround for now could be to map /cache.manifest to a controller action in the urlmappings and simply set the header manually.

In the action you can do something like this after setting the appropiate headers:

`response.outputStream.write(grailsApplication.applicationContext.getResource("/cache.manifest").getFile().bytes)`

Coded freehand, but you get the general idea.